Not able to connect EC2 through session manager
enter image description hereI am not able to connect to EC2 through session manager it's stating that plugin Standard_Stream not found
I have expanded the root volume but it's of no use still not working aws
this is the above error i am getting

Have you followed the docs?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started.html

no I don't know much about aws. I will go through this docs thx
